# INT(1) and INT(2) in Mysql Range and Limit to StoreData?

Tags: php, mysql

IN Mysql :

`INT(1) = 2147483647` and Store 4 byte,

then what about `INT(2) = ?` and Store `?` byte...

I used in INT(1) more than 2147483647 it does not work !
also I used in INT(2) with same value it does not work ?? Why ?

Solution ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL INT meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817479/mysql-int-meaning)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The optional display width specifier is only applicable when using **zerofill** and has nothing to do with the internal size (in bytes) of the integer data type. It is always 4 bytes.

This optional display width may be used by applications to display integer values having a width less than the width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces. (That is, this width is present in the metadata returned with result sets. Whether it is used or not is up to the application.)

Here's [a link] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)

**Example For More**

> drop table if exists tablename;
>
> create table tablename
>   (
>   columnname int(4) unsigned zerofill not null default 0
>   );
>
> insert into tablename (columnname) values (123),(456),(1234);
>
> select * from tablename;

**OutPut**

0123

0456

1234

Answer (score 5):

The parenthesised number represents the number of digits returned by the field. You can insert any number into an INT(1), but you will only get out a number between 0 and 9.

Comment: Brief explain with example

Answer (score 2):

INT in MySQL is always 4-byte number.

The syntax of INT type is INT(M), where M indicates the maximum display width; but not all MySQL clients supports this value.

Comment: But INT(2) with more than 2147483647 this value , its does not work , Why ?

Comment: INT: The signed range is -2147483648 to 2147483647. The unsigned range is 0 to 4294967295.

Comment: Have a look at Alepac's answer, you need another data type.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a BIGINT to get 8 bytes (See [Integer Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html)). The number in parentesis indicates only the maximum display width (See [Numeric Type Attributes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html))