# What is the difference between int(1) and int(2) in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am too much confused in Length/Values column in phpmyadmin.

[image]

Can any one explain me, What is the difference between int(1) and int(2)?

Comment: Check out the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL INT meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817479/mysql-int-meaning) or [int(11) vs. int(anything else)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552223/int11-vs-intanything-else)

Answer (score 2):

Its called display width, It will take a whole int, but only will display the first x numbers (so 1 will display 1 number, 2 will display 2)

The whole int is stored so its not like varchar, IF you want less storage use a smaller type (tinyint would suffice for both 1 and 2)

The types and how much they can store are here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: This will help us http://www.bajb.net/2008/10/mysql-int1-or-int10/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is the "width" or size of your number. int(2) means that it can be two digits, and int(3) means three digits, so on and so forth. I could be wrong, but let me know if this answers your question!

I know it works this way for varchar(n), so I'm thinking it's the same for int(n).

Comment: That's wrong. It simply is a hint for the application (client) on how wide the number should be displayed. It does not influence the values that can be stored in the value in any way.

Comment: This will help us http://www.bajb.net/2008/10/mysql-int1-or-int10/

Comment: Okay, TECHNICALLY it doesn't control the size in terms of digits, but it controls how many are displayed. Isn't "displaying" 1 digit out of however many the same exact thing as only having a 1 digit number? It isn't exactly the same - but what I'm saying is that in terms of actually displaying the field, it is the same. I did say the "width" of the number in my original answer - I gave the example that int(2) means two digits, int(3) is three digits, etc. My answer isn't incorrect, at all, from what I know. Please correct me if I'm wrong - I'd appreciate knowing.